# Rotate two rectangles Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a Rectangle with **20x20px** and a and another with **5x3px** like in the image

[image: Image of Rectangles]

I want to Rotate the entire Rectangle from the center.

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
//Rectangle
ctx.translate(pX,pY);
ctx.rotate((Math.PI/2*gravity));
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0, pHeight, pWidth);

//blue Rectagle     
ctx.translate(pX+(pWidth-5),pY+(pHeight/2));
ctx.fillStyle = "#000FFF";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,5,3);
ctx.translate(-(pX+(pWidth-5)),-(pY+(pHeight/2)));

ctx.rotate(-(Math.PI/2*gravity));
ctx.translate(-pX,-pY);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the second rotate and just draw the second rectangle offset as if it was non-rotated:

```
//Rectangle
ctx.translate(pX,pY);
ctx.rotate((Math.PI/2*gravity));
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0, pHeight, pWidth);

//blue Rectagle     
ctx.fillStyle = "#000FFF";
ctx.fillRect(pWidth-5, pY+(pHeight/2), 5,3);

ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);  // reset all transforms with identity matrix
```

Just note that as the code was and is the rectangle will be rotated from its corner. To adjust for that do this adjustment:

```
//Rectangle
ctx.translate(pX,pY);
ctx.rotate((Math.PI/2*gravity));
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(-pHeight*0.5, -pWidth*0.5, pHeight, pWidth);  // centered

//blue Rectagle     
ctx.fillStyle = "#000FFF";
ctx.fillRect(pWidth*0.5-5, 0, 5,3);  // centered

ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);  // reset all transforms with identity matrix
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/vLUYF/)**

Comment: it works. but when i run the animation the blue rectangle is getting away.

Comment: @Alaeddine could you set up a fiddle - it's easier to understand the problem that way as "animation" is very subtle. If you want to rotate them just animate the transformations (translate/rotate), no need to alter the positions for the rectangle.